# How do I get a jQuery var for img width and height to go to 50% in what I have so far?

Tags: jquery

This is a working trial of what I have
[24 hour Demo](http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite361700/website/)

I'm working within a program so I have to change the attributes to get this to work

The problem I have now is to get the image to go to 50% on hover for a preview before it uses

fancybox like shown in the Demo to go to the large image

 **This what I tried but it throws an error**

```
    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = 10;

$('a.nextfancy').hover(function(e) {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
.css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
.css('left', e.pageX + offsetX)
.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
$('#largeImage').remove();
});

$('a.nextfancy').mousemove(function(e) {
$("#largeImage").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
});
```

---- tried this ------

```
    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = 10;
    var halfSize = {maxWidth:"50%", maxHeight: "50%"};

$('a.nextfancy').hover(function(e) {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
.css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
.css('left', e.pageX + offsetX)
.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
$('#largeImage').animate(halfSize);
}, function() {
$('#largeImage').remove();
});

$('a.nextfancy').mousemove(function(e) {
$("#largeImage").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
});
```

Css on the image doesn't work it then goes to half the window size

I'm slowly teaching myself jQuery and cobbled this together...

Next I want to remove the title & keep it in the browser window but baby steps

If you show me this one I'm hoping I can figure out how to do that next part?

Comment: What is wrong with the demo? If I hover, it shows me a larger image. If I click, it opens in fancybox. What should be different?

Comment: I want the preview image on Hover to be scaled to 50% of the larger image Cymen

Comment: Have you tried .css("maxWidth","50%") similar to this in hover event

Comment: Yes I did sridhar I tried it in the style & in the jquery with .css but then the image only uses width & sizes to the window rather than scale the image to 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i prefer using `width()` and `height()` jquery function

it gets the height and width of the current element...and do the required calculation

do something like this....

**UPDATED**

```
var createdImg=$('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
 .css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
 .css('left', e.pageX + offsetX)
 .appendTo('body');

createdImg.css({'width':createdImg.width() * 0.50,'height':createdImg.height() * 0.50})
```

i am naming the img created ona fly to createdImg and changing the values of height and width after appending it...

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/chphQ/1/

Comment: That is getting closer I changed it to 1.50 it seems to get the size from the thumbnail? Have a look what it does in firefox though... weird http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite361705/website/

Comment: That is it.  http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite361706/website/   But I think with this I'd have to change from the document ready to window see how it doesn't change fast enough... but still it does work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/chphQ/

You need to change this:

```
$('a.nextfancy').hover(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />').css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX).appendTo('body');
}, function() {
    $('#largeImage').remove();
});
```

To this:

```
$('a.nextfancy').hover(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" height="50%" width="50%" />').css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX).appendTo('body');
}, function() {
    $('#largeImage').remove();
});
```

Note the setting of the height and width attributes in the 3rd line.

Comment: Nope I tried the css and this is what happens http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite361702/website/ which is why I was trying to do it with a variable

Comment: If it works on jsfiddle something else is making it not work on your test site. Perhaps you're overriding the CSS somewhere. You should fix that. That URL isn't loading for me unfortunately.

Comment: It was offline there for a sec should be good for you to see now Cymen

Comment: What the' Cymen that does work, ugh it has to be something in this program messing with it... what a pain. I'll mark it as correct since your code is good, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it using the css and had to use scaling, where you add the width then use auto for the height. The auto is the important part.

```
#largeImage {
position: absolute;
width:30%;
height: auto;
z-index:1000;
padding: 6px;
background: silver;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```